# Using Python's threading module to call ctypes function is faster than using multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I couldn't for the life of me figure out the answer to this problem.

I wrote a script that does hundreds of heavy computations. I have a brilliant idea of writing those computation tasks to C++ and then use Python's ctypes to interface with them.

I thought to myself, I could even optimise this further using parallelism. My initial approach is using threading. And then I realised my tasks are CPU-bound. Therefore, it only makes sense that we use multiprocessing instead. Well, turns out multiprocessing module is significantly slower than threading, probably due to the overhead.

And then I came across [this](http://caswenson.com/2009_06_13_bypassing_the_python_gil_with_ctypes.html). For those who don't want to click into a sketchy link, it turns out that the ctypes module bypasses the GIL. This means my attempt at Python's threading can achieve true parallelism.

So my question is: is there somewhere in the official documentation talks about ctypes and GIL?

I have attached the code I use to benchmark threading + ctypes and multiprocessing.

```
# Method 1: Using threading
start = time()

threads = []
for arg in args:
    threads.append(threading.Thread(target=some_ctypes_func, args=(arg, )))

for thread in threads:
    thread.start()

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()

print(f"Elapsed time: {time() - start}")

# Method 2: Using multiprocessing
results = []
with Pool(8) as p:
    start = time()
    for arg in args:
        result = p.apply_async(some_ctypes_func, args=(arg,))
        results.append(result)

    results = [result.get() for result in results]
    print(f"Elapsed time: {time() - start}")
```

Using the code above, the threading module is about 2 to 3 times faster than multiprocessing.

Comment: If you've already have function on C++ or any other native language, what's the point to use python for just execution of this threads? Isn't it better to implement also multithreading in C++?

Comment: @OlvinRoght Well, a single function finished its execution in less than a second. It is the execution of that function, with different inputs, hundreds of times more time-consuming. Also, Python provides a nice high-level interface to multithreading, which is nice.

Comment: I just want to point you that if you'll implement simple multithreading in C++ and export function which do all the job and return results, it will be much faster. Btw, there're lot of ways to implement multithreading in C++ with couple lines of code, not a big difference with python